# Адаптивная вёрстка сайта

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите как реализовать фоновое изображение, которое не будет изменять своих размеров при прокрутке Ctrl + колёсико [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: фоновое изображение на чём?

Comment: А вообще я не совсем понял, на скриншоте изображено как надо или как не надо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

на примере `body`:

```
background-image:url('...');
background-size:100vw;
```

размер фоновой картинки в пикселах ничего не даст, т.к. с точки зрения системы при масштабировании пиксели тоже меняются. А вот ширина вьюпорта останется неизменной, и 100vw всегда будет равно ширине окна браузера, какой бы масштаб вы не выкрутили.

Answer (score 1):

Можно задать размеры изображения явно в классе или теге:

```
height:XXXpx;
width:XXXpx;
```

Если изображение будет повторяться (при необходимости) добавить:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Это касается background-image. Если изображение используется как задний фон, например к хедеру, то в css файле, к тегу приписваем такой код:
header {
 background-image:url(../*.png);
 height:XXXpx;
 weight:XXXpx;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: @Drillneat, написали тот же код, что и в ответе:)

Comment: и не `weight`, a `width`:))

Comment: @St1myL, да, ошибся, там width.

Comment: Даже с `width` не верно.

Comment: Почему не верно? Если изображению задать размеры при "растягивании" сайта оно менять свои размеры не будет. Да это не лучший вариант, но он рабочий.